# How to write to a .csv file without "import csv"

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

For an assignment I have to write some data to a `.csv` file. I have an implementation that works using Python's `csv` module, but apparently I am not supposed to use any imported libraries...

So, my question is how I could go about doing so? I am no expert when it comes to these things, so I am finding it difficult to find a solution online; everywhere I look `import csv` is being used.

Comment: Look up [how to write to a file in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-to-file-in-python/) (not .csv file specificaly). Construct your lines manually and write them.

Comment: Ah, so the fact it is a `.csv.` is irrelevant? As long as it's the correct format, of course.

Comment: Yes, .csv files are regular files with .csv extension, that should (but don't have to) follow CSV format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `csv` stands for **comma-separated values**, you can create a file with the regular I/O built-in function that ends with `.csv` like:

```
f = open("demofile.csv", "w")
```

And then write to it:

```
f.write("1, 2, 3 ,4, 5\n 6, 7, 8, 9, 10")
```

Where each cell is *separated* by *comma*, and each row is separated by `\n`.

The result will look like this in `MS Excel`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the point of your assignment is not to have some else to do it for you online. So a few hints:

- organise your data per row.
- iterates through the rows
- look at concatenating strings
- do all above while iterating to a text file per line

Answer (score 1):

To create or open a file just use:

*(Second Parameter "w" -> Overwrite the file, "a" -> append to file, "r" -> read file)*

```
file = open("test.csv", "w")
```

Now you can write data to that file by using the write function:

```
file.write("surname,name,age,address\n")
```

When you are finished with writing to the file use

```
file.close()
```

[More information on W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)